# Need help about wildcard generic types in Java

Tags: java, generic-programming

I am learning generic programming in java.
I saw these charts in Core Java (Edition 9):

[image: ? extends T]

[image: ? super T]

And I saw these charts in Introduction to Java Programming Comprehensive Version Tenth Edition:

[image: Figure in the book]

But I believe it should be this instead:

[image: My Figure]

Could someone tell me whether I am right?

Comment: You're right, the book's wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The question is updated. Could you please advise me again?

Comment: Sorry, Sweeper. This is my first post in stackoverflow. I have already created a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655638/why-cant-i-put-an-object-of-superclass-of-b-into-container-super-b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  The mistake is listed in [the Errata for this edition](https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/liang/intro10e/errata.html) (which might be useful for similar confirmations in the future):

> Chapter 19
>
> **Page 749, Figure 19.6, change the last "A<B' subclass>" to "A<B'
> superclass>".**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should change from `A<B' s subclass>` to `A<B' s superclass>`.