# Why can't I put an object of superclass of B into Container<? super B>?

Tags: java, generic-programming

I have the code below. It seems that I can't put an object of class `Nonlife` that is a superclass of class `Vehicle` into a container of type `Collection<? super Vehicle>` **ALTHOUGH** there is a keyword "super" in the wildcard type, and only objects of class `Vehicle` and `SUV` that is a subclass of class `Vehicle` are feasible. Could someone give me some advice?

```
public class SUV extends Vehicle

public class Vehicle extends Nonlife implements Externalizable

public class Nonlife extends Thing

public class Thing implements Comparable<Thing>, Serializable

public class SupperWildcardTest20200830 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Thing> coll = new ArrayList<>();
        appendVehicle2Collection(coll);
        appendSuv2Collection(coll);
        for (Thing el: coll) {
            System.out.println("" + el);
        }
    }
    
    public static void appendVehicle2Collection(Collection<? super Vehicle> coll) {
        coll.add(new Vehicle());
    }
    
    public static void appendSuv2Collection(Collection<? super Vehicle> coll) {
        coll.add(new SUV());
    }
    
    public static void appendNolife2Collection(Collection<? super Vehicle> coll) {
        /**
         * incompatible types: Nonlife cannot be converted to CAP#1
         *  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
         *    CAP#1 extends Object super: Vehicle from capture of ? super Vehicle
         */
        coll.add(new Nonlife());
    }
}
```

Comment: reading this might be of use : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you know for sure about `Collection<? super Vehicle>` is that it is a collection of Vehicles, or a collection of a supertype of Vehicles. So the only thing you know for sure that you can put into this collection are Vehicles. So you are allowed to pass a Collection of NonLifes to the method, but you may still only put Vehicles or subtypes into the collection within the method.

In general: with super, you can put values of the mentioned type in it, or subtypes. With extends you can retrieve the mentioned type from the collection, or retrieve them as a supertype.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And later after I asked this question, I found a statement in Core Java Edition 9 the book as "Intuitively speaking, wildcards with supertype bounds let you write to a generic object, while wildcards with subtype bounds let you read from a generic object.". For now, I can only understand it generally like these statements (yous or the book's). Hopefully that one day I can understand it precisely by understanding the JVM and the Java compiler. But I guess that will be very far from now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Wildcard Capture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) problem.

TL;DR - when you use a wildcard (be it with `super` or `extends`) in the Generic Collection type definition, getting element from that collection and casting it appropriately can be considered *safe*, while adding element into the collection is not, and this mechanism is implemented for the safety purpose.

Let's examine the [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) given in the Oracle Documentation, which demonstrates the reason of why this safety is needed (*this example uses `extends` but same principle applies for `super`*):

The code:

```
import java.util.List;

public class WildcardErrorBad {

    void swapFirst(List<? extends Number> l1, List<? extends Number> l2) {
        Number temp = l1.get(0);
        l1.set(0, l2.get(0)); // expected a CAP#1 extends Number, got a CAP#2 extends Number;
        l2.set(0, temp); // expected a CAP#1 extends Number, got a Number
    }
}
```

does not compile, as it is attempting an *unsafe operation*, because, if you will invoke this method as follows:

```
List<Integer> li = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Double>  ld = Arrays.asList(10.10, 20.20, 30.30);
swapFirst(li, ld);
```

while `List<Integer>` and `List<Double>` both fulfill the criteria of `List<? extends Number>`, it is clearly incorrect to take an item from a list of Integer values and attempt to place it into a list of Double values.

Another example I liked is given by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), and it looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3716945/1553537).

You might also want to read [this](https://dzone.com/articles/java-generics-wildcard-capture-useful-thing-to-know).

Comment: Surely <? super Vehicle> reads as any type which is a superclass of Vehicle?

Comment: I’m just saying the first sentence seems misleading to me. A Car is a type which extends Vehicle. As I understand it, Car would not match <? super Vehicle>. Happy to be shown to be wrong though

Comment: @mattfreake I actually completely changed my (initially wrong) answer.

Comment: Hi @GiorgiTsiklauri, thanks for your answer. But my intent of this question is not about wildcard capture for SomeClass<?> and the helper method, but it is about why an object of the superclass cannot be set into SomeClass<? super T> although there is a keyword "super" in the wildcard type.